# Uninstalling package python3.10 nuked half of my system

Tags: apt, python3

I upgraded to the latest Ubuntu 22.04 LTS. Before I had python 3.9 but I needed 3.10 so I installed,

```
sudo apt install python3.10
```

After the update, the standard python was bumped to 3.10 so I no longer needed the `python3.10` package. I checked that python3 and python3.10 were different installations by,

```
which python3
/usr/bin/python3
which python3.10
/usr/bin/python3.10
```

So i decided to purge the 3.10.

```
sudo apt purge python3.10
```

This uninstalled a lot of packages like `xserver-common` and `gnome-terminal`. I was lucky enough to catch that so I ran,

```
sudo apt install python3
```

Which installed most of them back. I am so confused and petrified. `python3.10` and `python3` have reappeared in `bin`. Why? Where did I go wrong?

Comment: *"Where did I go wrong?"* - changing the python version on your system will break many packages. It's generally not a good idea to use software versions that conflict with your distribution, but changing the python interpreter is a particularly messy mistake. If you need a different version of python for some task, it's best to do so within an environment. If you can't figure out how to get back to before, it may be prudent to reinstall the OS.  Using the apt purge command in particular will also wipe any dependencies, so this can be hard to come back from.

Comment: Yeah but my question really is, should installing package x while a different version of x, say y is already installed as a different package, then uninstalling x, nukes your system? I mean ... if you ask me, this seems like a gigantic mistake on apt's side.

Comment: It's not apt's fault if you told it to do something destructive just like it's not a car's fault if you steer it into a ditch. With great power comes great responsibility. Packages in Ubuntu (Linux in general) rely heavily on dependencies. Ubuntu software is not like Windows software where every application comes packaged with all of its dependencies. This is why distributions use package managers and distro-specific repositories.

Comment: Ubuntu allows you to have multiple pythons installed, however you should **not** change the default version as many Ubuntu tools require that specific version to work properly.  If you change the default; you must avoid all tools that need *default* python which is hard for desktop systems, or users that rely on high-level tools like `apt` etc. If you've mucked up default; you should restrict yourself to low-level tools like `wget` & `dpkg` that don't need python to be the delivered version until the default version is back.

Comment: Also as the default `python` for Ubuntu 22.04 LTS is `python3 | 3.10.4-0ubuntu2 | jammy          | amd64, arm64, armhf, i386, ppc64el, riscv64, s390x` your mention of 3.9 makes me wonder what you'd done previously as 3.10 was already present.  Your details may imply you started with a *corrupt* system.  (*may also be I misread your issue; upgrade from impish maybe implied?*)

Comment: _Packages in Ubuntu (Linux in general)..._ comment comes a bit post-mature. I have used GNOO/Linox (wink) for a bit now. I am saying I was steering my car away from a ditch and fell into one, which imho should not have been dug.

Yes--I upgraded from impish which had Python 3.9. When I was still on impish, I installed the package `python3.10` which is different and as far as I know should have been independent of `python3`. After the upgrade, I uninstalled  `python3.10` since `python3 --vresion` was now also 3.10.

Comment: "your mention of 3.9 makes me wonder what you'd done previously as 3.10 was already present."


Note, I answered that, I'd done, `sudo apt install python3.10` on impish. And tried to undo it on jammy causing the fiasco...